# My Every JSONfunction related program suddenly same error occured is NullPointerException how i solve it?

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, android-studio

[Error occured nullPointer Exeptin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33e9y.png)

In MainActivity.java file error occur on line

new DownloadJSON().execute(); jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

there no fetch any array in every program,My database field value is Already Currect .Yet This line error null pointer exception.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
static String RANK = "rank";
static String COUNTRY = "country";
static String POPULATION = "population";
static String FLAG = "flag";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {         
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();           
jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("https://www.androidbegin.com/
tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String> ();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("rank", jsonobject.getString("rank"));
                map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                map.put("population", jsonobject.getString("population"));
                map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("flag"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

My Every JSONfunction related program suddenly same error occured is NullPointerException.before some times ago this error not occured.How i solve it?I use Eclipse Juno

There is my JSONfunctions.java class file which i use in my program

JSONfunctions.java

```
public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
InputStream is = null;
String result = "";
JSONObject jArray = null;

// Download JSON data from URL
try {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
}

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}

try {

    jArray = new JSONObject(result);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}

 return jArray;
}
}
```

logcat error:

```
10-15 18:25:49.835: E/(3836): appName=com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial, 
                             acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
10-15 18:25:49.835: E/(3836): 0
10-15 18:25:49.926: E/log_tag(3836): Error in http connection 
                 java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host 
                "www.androidbegin.com": No address associated with hostname
10-15 18:25:49.926: E/log_tag(3836): Error converting result 
                    java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
10-15 18:25:49.926: E/log_tag(3836): Error parsing data 
                  org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836): Process: 
                      com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial, PID: 3836
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836): java.lang.RuntimeException: An 
                    error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
                      android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
       java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
           java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
                    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
               android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
                    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
                    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
                    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
                    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
                    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836): Caused by: 
                    java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
                    com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.
              MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:64)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
                   com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.
               MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
                  android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at 
                   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-15 18:25:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     ... 4 more
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836): android.view.WindowLeaked: 
                    Activity com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.
                    MainActivity has leaked window 
                    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView
                    {41f618c8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,269} that was 
                    originally added here
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl. 
                    <init>(ViewRootImpl.java:422)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
      android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:250)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
          android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                                    android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
               com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.
               MainActivity$DownloadJSON.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:51)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                 android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                           android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                                 com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.
                                 MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                      android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                           android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
                           (Instrumentation.java:1088)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                           android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
                            (ActivityThread.java:2302)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                           android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
                           (ActivityThread.java:2390)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                           android.app.ActivityThread.access$800
                           (ActivityThread.java:151)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
       android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                                     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                        java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
                             (ZygoteInit.java:824)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
10-15 18:25:50.453: E/WindowManager(3836):  at 
                               dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check your url may be you splitted to next line by mistake.

Comment: i have solved url yet error occured.

Comment: Can you post your logcat's section which shows which line is actually causing error?